# Receiving NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass): from webhook callback Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webhooks

I built a webhook endpoint for a 3rd party API, but the issue I'm having is the webhook is failing to process some of the attributes that utilize arrays. I can't quite figure out why its not correctly updating/persisting the changes that the webhook is making in the system. How can I fix my webhook endpoint to allow changes to be made?

Error

```
  Started POST "/gh_webhook" for ..... at 2020-04-06 10:58:02 -0400
    Cannot render console from ....! Allowed networks: ..., ::1
    Processing by GHController#gh_webhook as HTML
      Parameters: {"Id"=>"459b58d7-5a9e", "ReportStatus"=>{"Id"=>"7eac420d", "Status"=>"New", "StatusDetails"=>"New", "CheckStatuses"=>[]}, "good_hire"=>{"Id"=>"459b58d7-5a9e", "ReportStatus"=>{"Id"=>"7eac420d", "Status"=>"New", "StatusDetails"=>"New", "CheckStatuses"=>[]}}}
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 1164)



NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):

app/controllers/gh_controller.rb:7:in `gh_webhook'
```

**GH webhook controller**

```
class GHController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def gh_webhook
    resp = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
    report_id = resp["Id"]
    candidate_first_name = resp["ReportStatus"]["Candidate"]["FirstName"]
    candidate_last_name = resp["ReportStatus"]["Candidate"]["LastName"]
    candidate_middle_name = resp["ReportStatus"]["Candidate"]["MiddleName"]
    candidate_email = resp["ReportStatus"]["Candidate"]["Email"]
    report_status = resp["ReportStatus"]["Status"]
    report_status_details = resp["ReportStatus"]["Pending"]
    report_adverse_action_status = resp["ReportStatus"]["AdverseActionStatus"]
    report_viewer_url = resp["ReportStatus"]["ReportViewerUrl"]
    candidate_url = resp["ReportStatus"]["CandidateUrl"]

    required_report_actions = resp["ReportStatus"]["RequiredReportActions"]
    check_statuses = resp["ReportStatus"]["CheckStatuses"]
    sections_containing_alerts = resp["ReportStatus"]["SectionsContainingAlerts"]

    background_check_report = BackgroundCheckReport.find_by_report_id(report_id) || BackgroundCheckReport.create(report_id: report_id)
    background_check_report.update(candidate_first_name: candidate_first_name, candidate_last_name: candidate_last_name, candidate_middle_name: candidate_middle_name, candidate_email: candidate_email, report_status: report_status, report_viewer_url: report_viewer_url, candidate_url: candidate_url, report_status_details: report_status_details, sections_containing_alerts: sections_containing_alerts, check_statuses: check_statuses, required_report_actions: required_report_actions, adverse_action_status: report_adverse_action_status)

    head :ok
  end
end
```

schema

```
 create_table "background_check_reports", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "candidate_first_name"
    t.string "candidate_last_name"
    t.string "candidate_email"
    t.string "report_status"
    t.string "report_status_details"
    t.string "report_viewer_url"
    t.string "candidate_url"
    t.bigint "provider_form_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "report_id"
    t.string "candidate_middle_name"
    t.json "sections_containing_alerts"
    t.json "required_report_actions"
    t.json "check_statuses"
    t.string "adverse_action_status"
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `"Candidate"` key in parameters hash so it is failing. Use `.dig` method to access value from nested hash or return `nil`

From documentation:

```rb
h = { foo: {bar: {baz: 1}}}

h.dig(:foo, :bar, :baz)           #=> 1
h.dig(:foo, :zot)                 #=> nil
```

UPD.

in line 7, 8, 9, 10 you have 'Candidate' key which could exist or could not exist in your hash.

replace `resp["ReportStatus"]["Candidate"]["FirstName"]`
 with `resp.dig('ReportStatus', 'Candidate', 'FirstName')` and you will have result if it exists or nil if `'ReportStatus'`, `'Candidate'` or `'FirstName'` doesn't exist. Then check whether your variable exist and

Comment: Can you give me a complete example. At which point in my code, would it be applicable to use dig?

Comment: Should I return nothing for attributes that return nil, instead? When its updating the report with only some attributes in the process. It would make sense to simply pass the attributes that exist, correct?

Comment: yes, before some actions just check if value presents, if not raise error or notify user or whatever you do.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have "Candidate" element in resp["ReportStatus"].
With your json:

```
resp["ReportStatus"] #=> {"Id"=>"7eac420d", "Status"=>"New", "StatusDetails"=>"New", "CheckStatuses"=>[]}

resp["Reportstatus"]["Candidate"] #=> nil

resp["ReportStatus"]["Candidate"]["FirstName"] #=> rise NoMethodError exception.
```

Comment: I'm testing the endpoint with new reports and it works without issue (Postman) It just breaks when its updating the record, I believe. Since some of those attributes are returning while others are not.